# Test Suite for testing scorm 2004

Tags: scorm, scorm2004

Is there any tool like Reload Player for 1.2 to test my scorm 2004 course. I know there exists
ADL and SCORM Test Track
ADL :
Takes a lot of time for installation
Test Track:
Take a lot of time uploading course when the file size is huge.

I am looking @ repeated testing and would prefere desktop installation. Any idea?. Currently i dont have access to SCORM 2004 LMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the official Test Suite:

http://www.adlnet.gov/Technologies/scorm/SCORMSDocuments/2004%204th%20Edition/Test%20Suite.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, Moodle doesn't support SCORM 2004 yet.

If you're interested, we (Rustici Software), sell licensed editions of SCORM Test Track that can be installed locally. More info at http://scorm.com/scorm-solved/test-track/test-track-licensing/

Comment: Yes Mike. I realised when I started testing. Will check with my manager. We would definitely need one as we go further.

Answer (score 0):

It's not perfect but for first-pass quick testing and troubleshooting I've been using the SCORM 2004 wrapper written by Claude Ostyn.

You can find it at: http://www.ostyn.com/standards/scorm/samples/scorm2004testwrapwrap.htm

Answer (score 0):

You have an online tool for testing/debuggin SCORM content... it is called SCORM Debugger and this is the website: https://www.scormtools.net/scorm-debugger

You can use this tool for testing, debugging, and validating SCORM content created with various authoring tools, such as Articulate Storyline or Adobe Captivate.

The SCORM Debugger includes features such as a console that displays all SCORM interactions, a real-time SCORM variable tracker, the ability to create restore points, and the option to share content with guests for remote testing and feedback.